# ls not updating to reflect new files?

Tags: linux, bash, file, ls

I am running a program that creates a bunch of files in a certain directory, and I want to watch the files get created.

I open two terminal windows and cd one of them (call it terminal A) to the directory of the program (so I can run it) and the other (terminal B) to the directory where the output files get written (this output directory starts out empty). When I `touch` a file in the output directory from terminal A then `ls` in terminal B, the new file appears -- all this behaves normally.

However, after I run the program in terminal A, none of the new files show up when I do `ls` in terminal B. Strangely enough, if I do `cd .` *then* `ls` in terminal B, the new files now get listed.

What is causing this behavior, and can I get around it?

Edit: Information about what is writing the files.

- Some are being written by calls to `cv2.imwrite(...)` in Python 2, using OpenCV.
- Some are being written by an `ofstream` in C++.

Comment: Could you include a [mcve] (your code)? We can only guess without having the hard facts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able reproduce this bug with anything else but this program I'm running, which is a large and confidential collection of code.

Comment: Then we won't be able to reproduce this *bug*, which is a reason for closure. Can you at least list the pertinent commands used in the script?

Comment: Thanks -- I'll find what I can and edit it into the question

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/702402/how-do-i-refresh-directory-in-bash.

Comment: @Simon Huh, now that you mention it, it is possible that this program is deleting and remaking the directory when I run it -- that would explain this behavior. I'll investigate and make sure that this is what's happening.

Comment: Yep, it appears that is what's happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sequence of events seems to reproduce the issue.

[image]

Your program in terminal A probably deletes terminal B's current directory and then recreates it with the same name, so `ls` doesn't work since that particular directory that was originally `cd`'d to by terminal B doesn't exist anymore. However, `cd .` brings you to the (now) re-created directory, at which point `ls` works again.

Comment: Looks like that's exactly what's happening -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This will happen if your second directory gets deleted and recreated.
Even if directory is deleted, but some process has it as current directory, file descriptor for it will remain open, and `ls` will show old content.
Executing `cd .` will force to close descriptor for now non-existent directory and reopen it again, now showing new content.